# Find the first index of a non-numeric character

Tags: ruby, regex, string

Suppose I have a `String`:

```
someString = "1374j03d42s23dc"
```

I want to find the first index of a non-numeric character. In this case, that would be `4`. How can I do this with a `regex`?

(I'm not very good at `regex`, so it would be great if the answer could explain what is going on)

Comment: `\d` is the short form for `[0-9]`, a digit from 0-9. Many (if not all) regex flavors support the opposite as well, which is `\D` - **not** a number. So, @sawa's asnwer is correct, see [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kX6nR2/1).

Comment: Asking an anonymous downvoter for an explanation is futile. Two miniscule points: it should be "the index of the first non-numeric character"; and the Ruby convention is use snake-case, not camel-case, for the names of variables and methods ("some_string" rather than "someString"). You don't have to follow the convention, of course, but 99%+ of Rubiests do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
someString =~ /\D/
# => 4
```

........

Answer (score 3):

In addition to sawa's solution: You could also use [`String#index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-index) when you like your code to be more readable:

```
string = '1374j03d42s23dc'
string.index(/\D/)
#=> 4
```

`/\D/` matches any non-digit (list of [common regexp metacharacters](http://rubular.com/))

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
someString.each_char.with_index { |c,i| puts i if c == someString.scan(/\D+/)[0] }
```